# Return to Activity from View in Android programming

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

I've been trying to find solution of this issue, but I haven't. The question is to return to **Activity** from **View**.
As soon as **if** statement become *false*, it should return me to **SplashActivity**
Here some Activities and View class, that perform all *logic* of application.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GameEngine gameEngine = new GameEngine(this);
    setContentView(gameEngine);
  }

}
```

Then goes my SplashActivity with one *ImageButton* which call MainActivity as soon as it's pressed.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity 
{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
  }

  //this method mentioned (onClick) in XML file I've not included.
  public void startGame(View view)
  {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
  }

}
```

My View Class:

```
public class GameEngine extends View
{
 boolean inGame;
 //Here some code...
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
 {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  if(inGame) 
  {
   canvas.drawBitmap(someImage, positionX, positionY, null);
   if(positionX > 100)
   {
     inGame = false;
     //Here I want to return to SplashActivity, where my ImageButton is!
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I don't know how to implement idea of returning to Activity and begin using my app from innitial point.
**Thanks in advance!**

**EDIT**

***This information is beside the point!***

Innitialy I changed code for better readability to touch on the main point.

This is inner class where it's updating:

```
public static class Drawable
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    Drawable(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return  y;
    }
    void update() {
        x -= 3;
    }
}
```

This is how myobjects actually draw

```
for (Drawable drawable : drawables) 
{
 //Draw upper pipe
 canvas.drawBitmap(pipeUp, drawable.getX(), drawable.getY(), null);
 //Draw lower pipe
 canvas.drawBitmap(pipeBot, drawable.getX(), drawable.getY() +
 pipeUp.getHeight() + GAP, null);
}
```

This is how it updates

```
private void animation()
{
 for(Drawable drawable : new ArrayList<>(drawables))
 {
  drawable.update();
  if(drawable.getX() == dWidth/3 + dWidth/3)
  {
   drawables.add(new Drawable(pipeX, (int)(Math.random() *
   (pipeUp.getHeight() -((pipeUp.getHeight() * 0.25))) - (pipeUp.getHeight() - (pipeUp.getHeight() * 0.25)))));
  }
    if(drawable.getX() <= 0 - pipeBot.getWidth())
    {
     drawables.remove(drawable);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I call *animation()* in onDraw method.

Comment: It is not considered good practice to do expensive operations inside `onDraw`, maybe you can found a better way to implement this.

Comment: @devgianlu may be, but that's the only way I know

Comment: You can probably do it where `positionX` is updated. Could you post that code?

Comment: You can try to use something similar to https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus (or any other approach with observer pattern. About pattern you can read here https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer )
post an event - catch it in your main activity and do any action you want. 
But keep in mind that onDraw - method which called a lot of times during view lifetime. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SplashActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(mainIntent);
```

or you can save reference of MainActivity in GameEngine's constructor and use it to open splash:

```
GameEngine gameEngine = new GameEngine(this);
```

or you can implement a livedata with a basic repository pattern:

```
public class DataRepository {
    public static MutableLiveData<Boolean> openSplash = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

On MainActivity:

```
DataRepository.openSplash.observe(this, aBoolean -> {
        if(aBoolean){
            //open splash
        }else{
            //
        }
    });
```

On GameEngine:

```
DataRepository.openSplash.postValue(true);
```

Comment: can you provide some exmaples of using 2nd and 3rd case please?